# Run other code after table view delete row animation is completed

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I am using the standard table view datasource protocol to delete table cells:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

I would like to run some other code once the animation is completed but the **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation** method does not have a completion block. How else would I run some code after this method completes?

Comment: Is `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` an option? Or are you trying to do this from somewhere that isn't the delegate and which would be difficult to connect to the delegate?

Comment: I actually tried that already but it didn't work.

Comment: Edit: It does work. There was a problem with my code that I was running but it's working now. Thanks!!!

Comment: I wasn't actually certain it would work, hence posting as a comment rather than a question — it struck me you'd possibly already tried but couldn't use it for some reason. I'll transport it down to the answers section...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For iOS 6 Apple added [`- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidEndDisplayingCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a) to [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You should be able to use it to get a callback immediately when each `UITableViewCell` has been removed from the display, so if you know you've started a deletion animation on a particular index path then you can use it as a usually reliable means of knowing that the animation has ended.

(aside: I guess if the user scrolled the cell off screen during its animation then you could get a false positive, but such things are going to be so unlikely that I'd be likely to add a basic guard against persistent negative consequences and not worry about the ephemeral ones, such as if I end up showing an empty cell when the mid-deletion object is scrolled back onto screen because I already removed it from my store)

Answer (score 2):

I believe one way to do this is to implement `UITableViewDataSource`'s method `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and execute a delayed performance method there inside.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete == editingStyle) {

        [self performSelector:@selector(delayedMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}

-(void)delayedMehtod {
    // Your code here...
}
```

It may not be as pretty as a "completion" block but I'm sure it would do the trick.

Hope this helps!